# How to give access to text file using if statement?

Tags: c, function

I am trying to give an if statement to check if a particular name is present in text file, then give access to it otherwise give error message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    printf("For person details, please enter the person name: \n");
    FILE * fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","r");
    int catch, i=0, index=0;
    char ch[100];

    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    if (scanf("%s", )){            // Don't know what to put here?
       perror("Error while reading!");
       return 0;
    }

    catch = fgetc(fr);
    while(catch != EOF){
        ch[index] = catch;
        if (ch[index] == ' '){
            ch[index] = '\0';
            printf("Here is your result: %s\n",ch);
            index = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else
            index++;
        catch = fgetc(fr);
    }
    fclose(fr);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Commenting on your "safe code" issues: Don't use scan() to get string value from a buffer, it would be wiser to use fgets() with strcapn() to change the newline character to NULL. In the files situation you can use also fread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply the program firstly opens a file and asks for a user input and verifies if the provided content is case-sensitively matched with the file. If so, then it'll let the program access the entire file and display on the screen, to do that, we must use another FILE b/c the old `*fp` is already manipulated and in case it's reused, it may display wrong data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"); // for verification
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("file.txt", "r"); // for future use
    char ch[50], str[50];
    short int FLAG = 0;

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", &str); // asks for input

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", ch) != EOF) {
        if (!strcmp(ch, str)) { // checks if a string matches provided by the user
            printf("Found! Here's your details...\n\n");
            FLAG = 1;
        }
    }

    if (!FLAG == 1) { // no? exits.
        printf("Not found, access denied!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    int c = fgetc(fp1); // yes? let's go...

    while (c != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c); // displays containing data
        c = fgetc(fp1);
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but here is one problem. How to show the details vertically. The data is stored in text file horizontally but I want to show it vertically one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a variable for your scanf output:

```c
char name[100];

if (scanf("%s", name) != -1)
  // ...
```

Then to compare both you'll use `strcmp`.

```c
#include <string.h>
//...

if (strcmp(ch, name) == 0)
  // both are equal
```

Note that you can access documentation for `scanf` and `strcmp` by typing `man scanf` or `man strcmp` in your terminal.

Comment: As I already mentioned, scanf isn't safe in the case of string input. You should change it to fgets().

Comment: Same result. Half details

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    printf("For person details, please enter the person name and id card 
    number: \n");
    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    char personName[100];
    scanf("%s", personName);
    printf("Enter your card number: ");
    int cardNumber;
    if (scanf("%d", &cardNumber)){ 
       printf("no error detected");
    }
    else{
       printf("error while reading");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope this is what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("For person details, please enter the person name: \n");
    FILE* fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "r");
    int catch, i = 0, index = 0;
    char ch[100] = { 0 };

    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        perror("Invalid file opening!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    fgets(ch, 100, fr);
    size_t len = strcspn(ch, "\n");
    ch[(len < 100) ? (len) : (99)] = 0; // For file safety checking
    if (strlen(ch)) {            // Don't know what to put here?
        perror("Error while reading!");
        return 1;
    }

    catch = fgetc(fr);
    while (catch != EOF) {
        ch[index] = catch;
        if (ch[index] == ' ') {
            ch[index] = '\0';
            printf("Here is your result: %s\n", ch);
            index = 0;
            memset(ch, 0, 100);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }

        catch = fgetc(fr);
    }

    fclose(fr);
    return 0;
}
```